# How do I format/pad a number to have at least 5 digits?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro which involves generating a filename and saving an excel sheet as pdf with that name.

I was able to generate target folder name as follows.

```
user_name = Environ$("UserName")
file_dir = "C:\Users\" & user_name & "\Documents\Jobs\"
```

The file name is created as follows.

```
Job_No = Site & "SV" & num_from_cell
PDF = Job_No & ".pdf"
file_path = file_dir & PDF
```

Currently the above code returns `MWSV234.pdf`. I want it to be `MWSV00234.pdf`. `num_from_cell` comes from one of the cells in Excel sheet.

In short, I want to left pad `num_from_cell` to 5 digits. Could you please tell me how?

Comment: Welcome to SO. To ask a question you must show your attempts to solve the problem so far. Please consider take a look at <https://stackoverflow.com/tour>. However, on `VBA` you could write a 5 digit number with the formula `Format(n, "00000")`, where `n` represents your number.